# django-admin.py does nothing when I execute it in visual studio

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm typing django-admin.py startproject project in my vscode terminal on windows, but when I do it just flashes a screen then closes and the project isn't created. It asked me what to open with and I chose python, but the command doesn't do anything. I'm not getting errors either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using django-admin.py instead of django-admin, problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create django app by typing folliwing command in terminal

```
python manage.py startapp HelloWorld
```

**Note**- It requires already created project.